# $n$ distinct real eigenvalues of an $n \times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for a real $n \times n$ matrix to have $n$ distinct real eigenvalues?

Ideally I'm looking for a test that does not require (and is hopefully more efficient than) computing the eigenvalues.

Comment: There are many ways to answer this question.  One possible answer is that all the blocks in Jordan Canonical Form are $1\times 1$, and are distinct and real.

Comment: ... It's characteristic polynomial has $n$ distinct real roots? ...  (This is equivalent to vadim123's and Peter Franek's condition, but differently computed.)  (Thanks to Peter Franek for correcting also me for dropping "real" the first time.)

Comment: @vadim123 Yes, but finding the Jordan Canonical Form is equivalent to just computing the eigenvalues.  Is there some test I can use to know without calculating what the eigenvalues actually are?

Comment: @user 160914 If the matrix is real symmetric, then it has $n$ real eigenvalues (not necessarily different). I don't think there is an equivalent reformulation that is simpler than "$n$ distinct real eigenvalues".

Comment: Once you have the characteristic polynomial, you could try to extract the number of distinct eigenvalues using Sturm's Theorem, but I can't imagine that is what you're looking for.

Comment: It is easy to use standard methods to find out if a polynomial has no repeated roots. $p(x)$ has no repeated roots if and only if $p(x)$ and $p'(x)$ are not relatively prime.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192421/obtaining-the-discriminant-of-the-characteristic-polynomial-directly-from-the-ma) seems like it might be useful here

Comment: Then again, the discriminant is only really helpful for sizes $3 \times 3$ and smaller